# How $y=\dfrac{1}{x}$ is derived from $\dfrac{x^2}{a^2}-\dfrac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ hyperbola

Tags: calculus, conic-sections

Unfortunately, I can't find the derivation of $y=\dfrac{1}{x}$ (1) from hyperbola canonical equation $\dfrac{x^2}{a^2}-\dfrac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ (2) in the internet.

I tried a bit to derive it on my own, but unsuccessfully, and the reason why I posting it here is that I doubt, that it really can be derived only from given - without additional conditions, for example, assuming, that $a=b$, or something similar.

Basically, as I understand (1) is (2) with coordinate axis rotated by some angle (45 degrees?), but I do not know, how to express it mathematically. Perhaps, I need somehow change $x$ and $y$ in (2), and after that try to express to (1) form.

---

**Major update**

I successfully derived the canonical equation (2), as a set of points, which absolute differenc of distances to two fixed points - focuses is constant.

In that case, I assumed, that focuses lie on X-axis. What if to just derive (1) the same way, assuming, that focuses are situated somewhere in first and third quarts?

Comment: Do you know anything about rotation matrices?

Comment: @EgorIvanov, a bit, from computer graphics. I remember, that there are sines, cosines, but I rather will answer, that I do not what it is. So (1) is obtained just by applying rotation matrix to (2)?

Comment: Can you see the rotational similarity between the first 2 plots [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/9zgz1zcei2)?

Comment: @SohamSaha, You mean the fact, that one function is kind of rotated another? Yes, I see it

Comment: Note: X and Y are not the same coordinates in both equations.

Answer (score 2):

Consider a plane with a hyperbola in it. Now impose $u$ and $v$ coordinate axes, in such a way that the hyperbola satisfies $v = \frac1u$. Now impose a new coordinate system in the same plane, with the same origin, with an $x$-axis going along the line $v = -u$ (positive direction in the fourth $uv$ quadrant) and a $y$-axis going along the line $v = u$ (positive direction in the first $uv$ quadrant). The units on the $xy$ axes are the same as they are on the $uv$ axes.

For any point with $uv$-coordinates $(u, v)$, the $xy$ coordinates of that same point are $\left(\frac1{\sqrt2}(u - v), \frac1{\sqrt2}(u + v)\right)$. On the other hand, if a point has $xy$-coordinates $(x, y)$, then the $uv$ coordinates of that point are $\left(\frac1{\sqrt2}(x + y), \frac1{\sqrt2}(x - y)\right)$. (If this isn't obvious to you, I strongly encourage you to actually take a pen and a sheet of paper, and *draw* these two coordinate systems on top of one another, and see that the coordinate translations are what I have said here.)

Now we turn our attention to the hyperbola. It consists of those points whose $uv$ coordinates $(u, v)$ satisfy the equation $uv = 1$ (which is to say, the product of the two coordinates is equal to $1$). But what if we have a point and it's $xy$ coordinates $(x, y)$ instead? How can we tell whether it is on the hyperbola? By using the above translation, of course!

If the $xy$ coordinates are $(x, y)$ then the $uv$ coordinates are $\left(\frac1{\sqrt2}(x + y), \frac1{\sqrt2}(x - y)\right)$. And we know that the point lies on the hyperbola if the product of their $uv$ coordinates equals $1$. So we get
$$
\frac1{\sqrt2}(x + y) \cdot \frac1{\sqrt2}(x - y) = 1\\
\frac1{2}(x^2 - y^2) = 1\\
\frac{x^2}2 - \frac{y^2}2 = 1
$$
So this is the equation for that same hyperbola when using the $xy$ coordinate system.

Comment: I need a time to understand this

Comment: @sahgasdvsadgv That is entirely fair.

Answer (score 2):

You can put the equation of a hyperbola in the form $xy=k$ only if it is a [*rectangular* hyperbola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbola#Rectangular_hyperbola), i.e. if its asymptotes are perpendicular between them. That happens if transverse and conjugate axis are equal: $a=b$.

If you take as coordinate axes the axes of the hyperbola, you get then its equation as:
$$
{x^2\over a^2}-{y^2\over a^2}=1.
$$
The foci, in this case, lie at $(\pm\sqrt2a,0)$ and the above equation is that of the locus of points whose distances from the foci have a fixed difference $2a$.

To obtain the other equation you must take instead as coordinate axes the asymptotes of the hyperbola. Doing so, the foci of the same hyperbola as above have coordinates $\pm(a,a)$. You can check that the locus of points $(x,y)$ whose distances from the foci have a fixed difference $2a$ obeys in this case the equation
$$
xy={a^2\over2}.
$$

Comment: I am trying currently something similar to what You wrote, and what @EgorIvanov wrote: in hyperbola initial definition equation: $|\sqrt{(x-l_x)^2+(y-l_y)^2}-\sqrt{(x-r_x)^2+(y-r_y)^2}|=2a$, where $l$ and $r$ are coordinates of "left" and "right" focuses, I tried to put "rotated" focuses: in canonical equation, focuses are: $(-c,0)$ and $(c,0)$, where $c=\sqrt(a^2+b^2)$, and I am trying to just rotate it by $\pi /4$, so it will become $(-\dfrac{c}{\sqrt{2}},-\dfrac{c}{\sqrt{2}})$ and $(\dfrac{c}{\sqrt{2}},\dfrac{c}{\sqrt{2}})$, just passing to the equation i wrote above but it is a difficult

Comment: @sahgasdvsadgv You cannot succeed unless you set $b=a$, in which case $c=\sqrt2 a$. The math is not so hard.

Comment: Also, according to what You wrote, $a=b$, so I probably should consider it, though, it is interesting, what it should be, without equaling $a$ and $b$. Yeah, that is what You wrote

Comment: @sahgasdvsadgv Without $b=a$ you won't get that simple equation, that's obvious if you think of it, because if $xy=k$ then cartesian axes are also asymptotes of the curve.

Comment: Okay, I still have not "opened" $c$, leaving it as it is, so it is not the problem currently

Comment: You also, probably meant everywhere in Your post and comments $c=\sqrt{2a^2}$

Comment: @sahgasdvsadgv Of course: as I wrote in my answer "foci lie at $(±\sqrt2{a},0)$".

Comment: Thank You, after multiple tries, I finally derived it, getting $y=\dfrac{a^2}{2x}$

Answer (score 1):

Let's use $\left(-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$-rotation matrix:
$$\begin{bmatrix}\cos\frac{\pi}{4} & \sin\frac{\pi}{4} \\ -\sin\frac{\pi}{4} & \cos\frac{\pi}{4}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}\frac{x + y}{\sqrt 2} \\ \frac{-x+y}{\sqrt 2}\end{bmatrix}$$
Now we check how hyperbola form is tranformed:
$$\left(\frac{x+y}{\sqrt 2}\right)^2 - \left(\frac{- x + y}{\sqrt 2}\right)^2 = 1$$
$$x^2 + 2xy +y^2 - \left(x^2 - 2xy + y^2\right) = 2$$
$$2xy = 1 \Rightarrow y = \frac{1}{2x}$$

Comment: Hmm, but its $2x$

Comment: Yes, because we need not only rotation. Moreover coordinates should be scaled by $\sqrt 2$. It can be clearly seen in the desmos demonstation in comments under your question.

Comment: So, $y=1/x$ is also scaled parabola, not only rotated (relatively to canonical one)?

Comment: @sahgasdvsadgv exactly!

Comment: Is not $-\pi /4$ rotating by clockwise, i.e. it should give $y=-1/x$?

Comment: @sahgasdvsadgv no, when "usual" hyperbola $y=\frac{1}{x}$ is rotated at $-\frac{\pi}{4}$ it becomes $x^2 - y^2 = 2$

Comment: Wait, but if it is scaled, as I understand only along X-axis, does not it mean, that now, not all points of $y=1/x$ hypebola have absolute difference of distances to focuses being constant? So, technically it is not a hyperbola at all? Oh, I can just check it

Comment: Wow, I just checked, and $y=\frac{1}{x}$ is not techically a hyperbola, but $y=\frac{1}{2x}$ is. Right?

Comment: @sahgasdvsadgv Why? Of course, $y=\frac{1}{x}$ is hyperbola, I used $x^2 - y^2=2$ to simplify notes, it can be rewritten as $\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2 - \left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2 = 1$

Comment: Because absolute difference of distances from each point to focuses (-1,-1) and (1,1) is not constant?

Comment: @sahgasdvsadgv None of these points is focus of $y=\frac{1}{x}$

Comment: Sorry again, I just read Wikipedia article about rotation matrix, and still do not understand why do You rotate canonical hyperbola by -45 degrees, instead of +45: we need to rotate canonical hyperbola by 45 degrees counterclockwise to reach $y=1/x$ hyperbola. According to Wikipedia, if system of coordinates is right-handed and rotation need to be aplied counterclockwise, then we have $x'=x\space cos \phi - y \space sin \phi$ and $y'=x\space sin \phi + y \space cos \phi$

Comment: Oh, I understand. You are rotating coordinate axis, and in this case, indeed rotation is clockwise 45 degrees, so -45 degrees. I was rotating hyperbola, more strictly - its focuses, so in that case it will be counterclockwise rotation, i.e. +45 degrees

Answer (score 0):

I also provide a solution, that combines my asumption, I wrote in the "major update" section of my post, supported by @EgorIvanov and @Intelligentipauca answers:

Since, hyperbola is a set of points, absolute diffrence of distances from each, to two fixed points, called focuses is constant, and equal some value $2a$, where $a$ - a constant, called major semi axis, the equation of hyperbola is:

$|\sqrt{(x-\phi_{1x})^2 + (y-\phi_{1y})^2}-\sqrt{(x-\phi_{2x})^2 + (y-\phi_{2y})^2}|=2a$ $(1)$

Where $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ are focuses points.

Hyperbola canonical equation $\dfrac{x^2}{a^2}-\dfrac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ is derived from $(1)$, considering focuses liying on X-axis and have coordinates $\phi_1(-c,0)$ and $\phi_2(c,0)$, where $c=\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$, where $b$ - a constant, called minor semi axis.

1. To derive $y=\dfrac{1}{x}$ $(2)$ equation, as @Intelligentipauca mentioned we need to restrict the hyperbola as rectengular hyberbola, since $(2)$ is exactly such hyperbola. To do that, we only need to consider $c=\sqrt{a^2 + a^2}=a\sqrt{2}$. Now focuses are $\phi_1(-a\sqrt{2},0)$ and $\phi_2(a\sqrt{2},0)$
2. Next, since, $(2)$ is actually rotated (and also scaled) on 45 degrees, relatively to $(1)$ hyperbola, using rotation transformation, @EgorIvanov mentioned, we need to rotate focuses by 45 degrees counterclockwise, so we will have focuses $\phi_1(-a,-a)$ and $\phi_2(a,a)$

Now, having initial conditions, that satisfy our needs, we can start to disassemble $(1)$:

$$|\sqrt{(x+a)^2 + (y+a)^2}-\sqrt{(x-a)^2 + (y-a)^2}|=2a$$

$$\sqrt{(x+a)^2 + (y+a)^2}=\sqrt{(x-a)^2 + (y-a)^2} ±2a$$

$$x^2+2xa+a^2+y^2+2ya+a^2=x^2-2xa+a^2+y^2-2ya+a^2±4a\sqrt{(x-a)^2 + (y-a)^2}+4a^2$$

$$4xa+4ya-4a^2=±4a\sqrt{(x-a)^2 + (y-a)^2}$$

$$x+y-a=±\sqrt{(x-a)^2 + (y-a)^2}$$

$$(x+y)^2-2a(x+y)+a^2=x^2-2xa+a^2+y^2-2ya+a^2$$

$$x^2+2xy+y^2-2ax-2ay+a^2=x^2-2xa+a^2+y^2-2ya+a^2$$

$$2xy=a^2$$

$$y = \dfrac{a^2}{2x}$$

Note, that as @EgorIvanov mentioned $(2)$ is also 2 times scaled hyperbola, not only rotated, so if we want to get exactly $(2)$, besides the rotation of focuses we also needed to divide $x$ by $2$ in $(1)$, but you can do it on your own.

Comment: Equation $y={1\over x}$ IS that of a hyperbola: just choose $a=\sqrt2$.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca, yeah, but other poster mentioned, that this hyperbola is also two times scaled (relativeely to canonical), but now I see, that this equation comes not only from dividing $x$ by 2 in initial equation, but just by considering $a$ as $\sqrt{2}$, so $2$ in denominator is canceled. And because we didn't scaled $x$, but only choose $a$, it seems for me, that it is not scaled. Probably, in this case just the focuses, instead of $x$ are somehow scaled, but still a bit weird